# Bug code OpenAI weigh normalization get_variable tf1.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization, normalization

I'm trying to use the source code of OpenAI which implements weight normalization (Saliman's paper).
https://github.com/openai/weightnorm/tree/master/tensorflow

The code works very well on tf 1.1. But I can't make it work on tf 1.4...

There is a bug during the initialization (data driven initialization of weights). It seems that tf can't create the variables after some point. It creates very slowly first weights and then freezes. Here is the code I'm trying to use on tf 1.4:

```
@add_arg_scope
def conv2d(x, num_filters, filter_size=[3,3], stride=[1,1], pad='SAME', nonlinearity=None, init_scale=1., counters={}, init=False, ema=None, **kwargs):
    ''' convolutional layer '''
    name = get_name('conv2d', counters)
    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        if init:
            # data based initialization of parameters
            V = tf.get_variable('V', filter_size+[int(x.get_shape()[-1]),num_filters], tf.float32, tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.05), trainable=True)
            V_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(V.initialized_value(), [0,1,2])
            x_init = tf.nn.conv2d(x, V_norm, [1]+stride+[1], pad)
            m_init, v_init = tf.nn.moments(x_init, [0,1,2])
            scale_init = init_scale/tf.sqrt(v_init + 1e-8)
            g = tf.get_variable('g', dtype=tf.float32, initializer=scale_init, trainable=True)
            b = tf.get_variable('b', dtype=tf.float32, initializer=-m_init*scale_init, trainable=True)
            x_init = tf.reshape(scale_init,[1,1,1,num_filters])*(x_init-tf.reshape(m_init,[1,1,1,num_filters]))
            if nonlinearity is not None:
                x_init = nonlinearity(x_init)
            return x_init
```

It successfuly creates first layers but after one time it freezes forever. Here is the message I get if I stop the program:

```
 File "train_gan_cifar.py", line 309, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train_gan_cifar.py", line 100, in main
    dis(unl, is_training_pl, init=True)
  File "/home/bruno/ssl-project/cifar_gan.py", line 35, in discriminator
    x = nn.conv2d(x, 192, nonlinearity=leakyReLu, init=init, counters=counter)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 181, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/bruno/ssl-project/nn.py", line 192, in conv2d
    g = tf.get_variable('g', dtype=tf.float32, initializer=scale_init, trainable=True,validate_shape=False)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1203, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1092, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 425, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 394, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 805, in _get_single_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 213, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 345, in _init_from_args
    self._build_initializer_expr(self._initial_value),
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 777, in _build_initializer_expr
    new_op = self._build_initializer_expr(initial_value.op)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 796, in _build_initializer_expr
    new_tensor = self._build_initializer_expr(tensor)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 777, in _build_initializer_expr
    new_op = self._build_initializer_expr(initial_value.op)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 796, in _build_initializer_expr
    new_tensor = self._build_initializer_expr(tensor)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 777, in _build_initializer_expr
    new_op = self._build_initializer_expr(initial_value.op)
  File "/home/bruno/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/sit
```

The last lines is repeated many times.

Answer (score 0):

You may try add a line:

```
inp = tf.map_fn(tf.identity, inp)
```

This works for my case, but I still dont know why it works.